# Illegal string offset 'url'

Tags: php, wordpress, php-5.6

I am getting this error (Illegal string offset 'url') on 2 webpages of my website.  I am currently on windows plesk hosting of Godaddy. I don't understand much of PHP.

Here is my code, i am getting error in a line.

Here is the code of that line
////

```
  .'<img src="'.get_field('image')['url'].'" alt="user-image" />'
```

///

Apologies for the edit.

Comment: You should get an error there. A different one.

Comment: I get this error on that page: PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'url' in on line.
And, I got warning asking not to share code.

Answer (score 0):

May be get_field is a function, in that case it must be...

```
.'<img src="'.get_field ( $image ) .'" alt="user-image" />'
```

since the parameters of a function must be enclosed by "( )"

Comment: This is the line of code where i am getting error,
.'<img src="'.get_field('image')['url'].'" alt="user-image" />'

Comment: This is a code that put the url for the img and it gets it using the "get_field" function...
If you are using wordpress may be the info you need is this: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/
or something similar. Hope it helps

Comment: another approach, https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/
to share more of the code just try to open or edit the involved file and select as much text as you can, copy and paste it in here